# chartjs xaxis ticks with round values from shifted input data

Tags: chart.js

I'm working on a project using chartjs for displaying data.

The problem is: results in my dataset's x axis are far from any round number like so:

```
10932.719983363277
12560.833900691468
14190.798503260216
15822.383289061858
17456.06882152693
19092.218364565953
20729.378152457735
22368.86437683459
24010.600817095823
25654.16468236109
```

I need chartjs to display ticks on x axis rounded to some base step value like 5000, 2000 depending on results range. The callback for ticks can only alter the text but what I need is to draw complete new ticks referencing the values on graph that were not in original dataset (in this example 2000).

To help visualize the issue check out the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lsxfdfyg/

Despite the messy xAxes input i'd like to keep the scale constant and rounded up to some readable values.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna modify ticks on x-axis, you can do it by using **afterBuildTicks**.

```
xAxes: [{    
    afterBuildTicks: function(mychart) {
        mychart.ticks = [];
        mychart.ticks.push(0);
        mychart.ticks.push(2000);
        mychart.ticks.push(4000);
        mychart.ticks.push(5000);
    }
}],
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. The issue is not with the ticks caption but with the dataset itself. It's easy to change existing tick caption but it does not affect the tick position on the chart. It requires some additional math to calculate it's position based on the dataset range. It's done on Y axis so i was hoping You can do it on X axis without reinventing the library.